# Can't add numbers

Tags: python-3.x

```
x = 1
while x:
    if x < 100:
        x + 1
    if x == 100:
        break
print(x)

x = 1 
while x < 100:
    x =+ 1
print(x)

x = 1 
while x < 100:
    x + 1
print(x)

x = 1
while x is not 100:
    x + 1
print(x)
```

I absolutely cannot figure out why this will x will not return the value of 100. Each instance of 'x = 1" being a different attempt at acheiving my goal.

I just want to create loop that add one to x each time until it reaches 100, then prints the value of x.

Comment: Your operator is "misspelled". `x =+` 1 should be `x += 1`

Comment: Also `x + 1` creates a new number but you don't assign it into anything. It does not change `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for completeness:

- `x + 1` creates a new number but you don't assign it into anything.
  It does not change x -- use `x = x + 1`

  `x =+ 1` should be `x += 1`

  `for i in range(100): print(i)` is a more Pythonic way of iterating through a range

Answer (score 1):

You never rebind the incremented value back to the name.

```
x = x + 1
```

...

```
x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way (that I use) is using a for-loop as shown:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 101; $i++) {
    echo $i;
}
```

I am actually not very familiar with Pyton, but Python, Javascript and PHP are all three based on Java, so I am certain that this will work. Otherwise, I tried what I could, sorry.